# Proving that $(a+b)^p + (a-b)^p \geq 2a^p + p(p-1)a^{p-2}b^2$ for $p \in [1,2]$ and $0 \leq b \leq a$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, inequality

I have found that this is true for $p=1,  2$ and was trying to show the function $f(p) = (a+b)^p + (a-b)^p -2a^p - p(p-1)a^{p-2}b^2 \geq 0$ for $p \in (1,2) $ but have been unable to do so. I differentiated it twice to show that concavity on the interval would guarantee so but was unable to prove so.

Also I know $(a+b)^p + (a-b)^p \geq 2a^p$ by convexity of $x^p$ but haven't found a way to account for the last term. It looks a lot like a derivative but I'm not quite able to proceed with that knowledge.

Comment: Actually, it's a truncated binomial theorem. For this case, see my answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inequality concerning nonnegative numbers (related to Hanner's inequalities)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/309644/inequality-concerning-nonnegative-numbers-related-to-hanners-inequalities)

Answer (score 3):

$f(p) 
= (a+b)^p + (a-b)^p -2a^p - p(p-1)a^{p-2}b^2 
\geq 0
$

Letting
$g(p)
= f(p)/a^p
$
and
$c = b/a$,
$g(p)
= (1+c)^p + (1-c)^p -2 - p(p-1)c^2
$.

Let
$h(c)
= (1+c)^p + (1-c)^p -2 - p(p-1)c^2
$.
$h(0) = 0$.

$h'(c)
=p(1+c)^{p-1}-p(1-c)^{p-1}-2p(p-1)c
=p((1+c)^{p-1}-(1-c)^{p-1}-2(p-1)c)
$
so
$h'(0) = 0$.

Then
$h''(c)
=p(p-1)((1+c)^{p-2}+(1-c)^{p-2}-2)
$.

$h''(0) = 0$
and
$h'''(c)
=p(p-1)(p-2)((1+c)^{p-3}-(1-c)^{p-3})
\gt 0
$
since
$p(p-1)(p-2) < 0$,
$0 < (1+c)^{p-3} < 1$,
and
$(1-c)^{p-3} > 1$.

Therefore,
working our way back,
$h''(c) > 0$
for $0 < c < 1$,
$h'(c) > 0$
for $0 < c < 1$,
and, finally,
$h(c) > 0$
for $0 < c < 1$.